# Why do we need beans.xml while working with JSF web application?

Tags: jsf-2, javabeans

I started web development using JSF, after studying JSP and Servlets for a while.

When you create a JSF web application you always(may be often but I am not sure if it always or not) have to create beans.xml and you don't write anything in it. But, if that file doesn't exist the JSF web app will not work.

What is the reason behind that?

Why we need that file?

Please, detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to the answer of Micheal; CDI is not only useful in combination with JSF because of the injection support, but also because of its support to be used with EL (expression language). This is a feature JSF heavily depends upon.

In fact, CDI beans can almost entirely replace JSF managed beans and therefor you'll find lots of examples using them and a good amount of JSF books advising their use. For JSF applications CDI beans have e.g. the following advantages:

1. Can inject smaller scopes into larger scopes. E.g. request scoped GET parameters can be injected into a session scoped bean. This is not possible with JSF managed beans.
2. Can take advantage of the conversation scope; a scope that spawns multiple different pages.

Very unfortunate is that in JSF 2.0 and 2.1 the extremely handy view scope is not supported by CDI beans by default, although extensions like Seam can add these. (update: in JSF 2.2 there's a new view scope that does work with CDI beans)

All in all the confusion between JSF Managed beans and CDI beans is such that there's a JSF spec issue for this, see http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-976

Comment: I really appreciate your help guys. Since I am just beginning studying JSF, I couldn't get the clear idea of Dependency and Injection (why wee need them?), the difference between CDI beans and managed beans. It is because the examples I have done so far don't need dependency and injection. I hope when I understand them, I will be able to understand what you guys answered.

Comment: @user636195: It's "dependency injection", no "and" - it's a mechanism that injects dependencies into components rather than having the components be responsible for getting references to the things (dependencies) they need. It's a rather abstract topic, but the main benefit is increased flexibility. Managed beans are actually a (somewhat limited) form of dependency injection, one that has been part of JSF from the beginning, while CDI is more feature-rich form that represents an official standard and is not exclusively tied to JSF.

Comment: CDI beans can now be view scoped in Java EE 7 (needs to be edited the answer now, I think).

Comment: @Tiny Indeed, since some time actually (we wrote our own implementation for OmniFaces, and JSF 2.2 contains one by default)

Answer (score 4):

The presence of a beans.xml file signals the servlet container that the application uses JSR-299 (Contexts and Dependency Injection) - without it, the application's classes will not be scanned for CDI annotations either and dependency injection will not be performed. If you don't use CDI (e.g. you only use plain JSF managed beans), you don't need beans.xml. If you do, you can use the file (instead of annotations) to define CDI configurations - this allows you, for example, to provide a test configuration where some dependencies are replaced with mocks.

Answer (score 0):

From [Getting Started with Contexts and Dependency Injection and JSF 2.x](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/cdi-intro.html)

> When the application is deployed the server looks for CDI managed beans. In a Java EE 7 application, the classes on the path are scanned for CDI annotations by default. In a Java EE 6 application, the classes are scanned for CDI annotations if the module contains a beans.xml file.